# Can't get the correct music folder

Tags: java, android, directory

I can't find out the correct folder to load my audio file.
I'm using an Android device which has no SD card but if I connect it via USB to my PC I will see the directory "Phone" with the subdirectory "Music".
In that directory I placed a mp3 file "Play.mp3" and then I tried the following variations to get a file reference:

```
File file = new File("/Phone/Music/Play.mp3");
File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC), "Play.mp3");
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC), "Play.mp3");
```

But in each case file.exists() returns false.

Comment: Have you tried File file = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory() + "/Phone/Play.mp3"); You wouldn't want to use external because you aren't using an sd card.

Comment: It's unfortunately the same result - the file could not be found.